# Auth::check() returning false in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.4 as backend for my application and for front-end I am using angular. I am using laravel `auth` for authentication.

Issue is `Auth::attempt()` is working fine and if immediately I print the `Auth::user()` then it prints the data but it returns `false` if I try to fetch it in next method. But this functionality is working fine in hosted server.

Tested,

1. Changing session from file to database.
2. Changes in kernel.php (Content of $middleware).
3. Did php artisan make:auth one more time.
4. Did changes in user table column.
5. Adding private $primarykey = 'id' to model.
6. Adding 'web' middleware to all routes.

This is my Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;

public function login()
{
 if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password ])) 
        {
            $response = array('response' =>'Succssfully Login!' , 'success' => true);

            return $response;
        }
 }
```

This is where i am using `Auth::check()` in the same controller

```
public function check() 
{
    if(Auth::check())
        $response = array('response' =>'Authenticated' , 'success'=>true);
    else
        $response = array('response' =>'UnAuthenticated' , 'success'=>false);

    return $response;    
}
```

I am confused because same code is working fine in hosted server but not working on localhost. Do I need to do any http related changes in laravel for this?

Comment: are you loading your angular index.html using blade template or its on a completely different server / p.s. is the angular app not loading from laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your Angular application is outside laravel, and loading without using blade template to load your Angular app's entry point i.e. Angular's `index.html` then what happens is Laravel is not able to set session for the app, hence when you request for the next time your laravel is not able to recognise the session so it gives `false` when you call `Auth::check()`.

To achieve authentication on external (i.e Angular app on your case) you should use either Laravel Passport's password client or JWT based authentication using `https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth` <- this package. (Instructions on the package's readme file)

For angular and web based app I would prefer to go with JWT.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, You are right basic Auth will not work for combination of laravel and angular, But i am surprised to see it working on hosted server. As you suggested i am going for jwt-auth.